# User defined function to take integers as input and change it to string to perform index+match and return result

Tags: excel, user-defined-functions

I have a "pay matrix" table. I will try to explain in brief.
Column A4:A43 is called as Level and Range B3:T3 is referred as cell.

The only problem is that one cell "O3" has a value 13A. Hence I am facing difficulty in index-match operation.
[Please see the link to excel sheet that I am referring to](https://www.dropbox.com/s/8o6s29cexdofpot/CPC.xlsm?dl=0)

I overcame the issue by converting cell value and level value as string and used index,match functions.

I would like to have a user defined function that picks integers from two different cells and convert the numbers to strings and do above index-match operation and return result in a cell.

I am facing difficulty in converting integer value to string value inside custom function.

Please help!

Comment: If you need help with your function code, then you should include it in your question.  People here typically don't download sample files, particularly xlsm.

Comment: Ok, thanks for your feedback. I shall post the vba code.

Comment: I have managed to solve the problem using in buit excel functions. And as per your feedback, I have attached a screenshot of the problem and the formula that I used.   https://www.dropbox.com/s/r89yrat36ltbnun/ScreenShot029.jpg?dl=0               Basically, I converted values in two cells into strings and performed index and match operations. But I do not know how to write a user defined function that takes arguments from two cells and convert them to strings to perform the operations